# Regression with Tensorflow model. Training loss > Validation Loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression

I need to estimate a continuous value and have a dataset with 11 fields + the one to be estimated. Therefore I "cleaned" the data, optimized with MinMaxScaler, shuffled the rows and proceded to create my model. By the way is a 127K dataset and my testing data is 20%. Here's a snippet of the model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
 learning_rate=0.01, 
 beta_1=0.9, 
 beta_2=0.999, 
 epsilon=1e-07, 
 amsgrad=False,
 name='Adam'),
 loss='mse')
```

The fit:

```
model.fit(x=X_train,y=y_train.values,
          validation_data=(X_test,y_test.values),
          batch_size=128,epochs=100)
```

But the outcome:

```
losses = pd.DataFrame(model.history.history)
   losses.plot()
```

The history shows big gap between the training loss and the validation loss:
[image]

I've tried adding a dropout layer between both the input and the middle layer but it only makes it worse.

Comment: Some ideas might be found at https://twitter.com/aureliengeron/status/1110839223878184960

Comment: Hi Javier. What is your question exactly?

Comment: Well I don't think the fit is right. So I'm wondering what's wrong with the model. I haven't tried any predictions so far though @zabop

Comment: @AlexL the twitter post helped a lot. I actually replied to it, asking for a little example and Aurèlien posted a bit of a solution. I did a little more digging and added regularization on each layer. The loss history still don't look weird, but the Explained Variance Score is 0.96 so I't looks accurate enough